# Can not get relationship data using Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am working with Laravel 5.4. I am using Eloquent ORM. I have created to table as Countries and States. Both are dislpay as below :

Countries Table :

[image]

States Table :

[image]

Now, I have wrote two method to set relationship between States and Countries table.

Country Model :

```
public function states()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Masters\State')->select('*');
}
```

State Model :

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Masters\Country')->select('name as country_name');
}
```

Now, I am going to create edit functionality so I can not get country name.

I have written query as

```
$state = State::with('country')->find($id);
return Response($state);
```

Here, I got only state data and country data as null.

So what should I have to change to get state as well country data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather not use `select` in your relationships. When you use only name of country Laravel won't be able to link this with your state, so it won't work.

You should define your relationships like this:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Masters\Country::class);
}

public function states()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Masters\State::class);
}
```

without selects